# import data from hbase to hdfs using talend or sqoop

Tags: hbase, hdfs, sqoop, talend

Is it possible to use Talend or sqoop to export data from hbase to hdfs? If it is not directly available , what kind of workaround are the best practices to achieve such a usecase

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with talend.

In the **Bigdata version** of talend you have hdfs component and hbase component.
You need to put tHbaseinput -> tmap -> tHDFSOutput.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its possible !

Using Talend as mensioned by @Théo answer, but not with Sqoop, because its **Sq**l to Had**oop** not Inter-Hadoop solution, may be there is a workaroud to do it using Sqoop, but this is not it's ideal use case.

But in fact, HBase store its data in the HDFS. If you want to export them as files or to query them using Hive, you can create a Hive table that read HBase data, see [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration).